# Out of bounds exception when confirming a user

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to set up AWS Cognito email verification for my app. However, when the email verification number is typed in and the user clicks the verify button, I keep getting a

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

I understand what this means however I am learning as I go, so I am struggling to find exactly where the issue is made.

I have already researched the issues over Stack Overflow and have not found any help directly relating to this issue and amazon cognito. I have tried adjusting the array size and tried to make different catch senerios to see where the code goes wrong.

Here is the Java file that the error comes from

```
public class verify extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static  final String TAG = "Cognito";
    private CognitoUserPool userPool;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);

        final EditText verifyCode = findViewById(R.id.verifyCode);

        Button verifyButton = findViewById(R.id.verifyButton);
        verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new ConfirmTask().execute(String.valueOf(verifyCode.getText()));
                Intent intent = new Intent(verify.this, stepTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class ConfirmTask extends  AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            final String[] result = new String[1];

            final GenericHandler confirmationCallback = new GenericHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    result[0] = "Successful!";
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception exception) {

                    result[0] = "Failed " + exception.getMessage();
                }
            };

            CognitoSettings cognitoSettings = new CognitoSettings(verify.this);

            CognitoUser thisUser = cognitoSettings.getUserPool().getUser(strings[1]);

            thisUser.confirmSignUp(strings[0], false, confirmationCallback);

            return result[0];


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.i(TAG, "Confirmation result: " + result);
        }
    }

}
```

I expect the app to not crash and for the Amazon Cognito User Pool to show that I have verified the email. 
Here is my logcat

```
2019-09-04 18:02:51.418 18206-19048/com.example.medicut E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.medicut, PID: 18206
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at com.example.medicut.verify$ConfirmTask.doInBackground(verify.java:64)
        at com.example.medicut.verify$ConfirmTask.doInBackground(verify.java:41)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: "`new ConfirmTask().execute(String.valueOf(verifyCode.getText()));`" looks a lot like you are only passing a single parameter; but you're trying to access a second parameter in the task body, via `strings[1]`.

Comment: `CognitoUser thisUser = cognitoSettings.getUserPool().getUser(strings[1]);`

Are you sure your strings have length of `2`?